# Formatting JSON text into readable

Tags: python

I'm attempting to format this JSON text into human-readable, and I've been having a few errors.

`"extra":[" ",{"color":"dark_red","text":"- "},{"color":"red","text":"Released today @ 3PM EST"}],"text":""}{"text":""}{"extra":[{"bold":true,"color":"gold","text":"Battle Pass: "},{"color":"gray","text":"You do not have premium "},{"color":"gold","text":"Pass"},{"color":"gray","text":"."}],"text":""}{"extra":[{"color":"gray","text":"You can buy this at anytime and receive premium rewards."}],"text":""}{"extra":[{"color":"gray","text":"Purchase a "},{"color":"gold","text":"Pass "},{"color":"gray","text":"copy: "},{"underlined":true,"color":"white","clickEvent":{"action":"open_url","value":"http://store.example.net"},"text":"store.example.net"},{"color":"gold","text":" [50% Off]"}],"text":""}{"text":""}`

I have this saved as a variable `msg`. Since it's only the `'text'` I'm interested in, I tried doing `print(msg['text'])`, but this didn't work. Should I split it into lists and then deal with them that way? Or is there a really simple way to do this with JSON library that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Look into `pprint` module.  Specifically, `from pprint import pprint; pprint(msg)`

Comment: Are you actually working with JSON here? Please provide a [mcve]. What exactly do you mean by "I tried X and it didn't work", **how did it not work**?

Comment: The text you show is pretty clearly not valid JSON. It appears to be a sequence of JSON fragments, with the opening `{` of the first one cut off. It would help if you showed how you got this data in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid `json` file or string, one way to make it more human-readable is to use the `indent` keyword parameter, e.g.

```
import json


d = {i: str(i) for i in range(10)}
s = json.dumps(d)
print(s)
# {"0": "0", "1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5", "6": "6", "7": "7", "8": "8", "9": "9"}

ss = json.dumps(json.loads(s), indent=4)
print(ss)
# {
#     "0": "0",
#     "1": "1",
#     "2": "2",
#     "3": "3",
#     "4": "4",
#     "5": "5",
#     "6": "6",
#     "7": "7",
#     "8": "8",
#     "9": "9"
# }
```